# Is it possible to color single-line and multi-line comments differently in SQL Server Managment Studio?

Tags: ssms, syntax-highlighting

I'm using SSMS v18 and would like to be able to distinguish single-line and multi-line comments at a glance. For instance, I'd like to have something like the following:

```
\* Multi-line comment
** This would be coloured dark blue 
** Or something like that */

SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition = 0
-- AND this_line_colour = 'dark_green'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not without using third-party extensions, no.

Comment: Also, why aren't you using SSMS19?

Comment: At the moment, this is what my job has me use; it's in an area that's rather slow/resistant to change. Is there a third-party extension you know of that has this functionality?